# use windows boot to restore files permissions

Tags: windows-7, boot, permissions, file-permissions, ext

Accidently, I have done `sudo chown` to all my files  - recursively, from the root directory. so my ubuntu is no longer bootable.

I'm trying to be creative, and as my computer has a dual boot windows installation, I seriously hope there are some ways that i can fix the broken ownership settings from there.

I have installed a ext driver, and now the linux partitions is accessible from windows file explorer.

is there any way i might fix those permissions?

thanks

Comment: This is when you pat yourself on the back for keeping good backups.  Just restore and be on your way.

Comment: backup is not needed at all. all files are accessible from windows

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do in this situation is try to recover via a recovery os. Doesn't have to be anything specific, but you can install ubuntu live on a usb stick. boot in live mode and mount your previous os. i would stay away from changing anything in windows. you could introduce MS file endings and all kinds of weird behavior.

this is mainly to help you get your files off however. because as @SDsolar already said, backups are your best friend. if you did not make any backups this might help you get some files back.

heres the problem though. you cant just chown everything back. you will either leave the system unusable, as the user doesnt have enough permissions on the right files, or you introduce vulnerabilities, as a user has access to something he should not.

to really go back to the way it was you would have to remember the ownership of each and every file on the system. thats a pain.

boot to live cd (if you dont already have backups) save files.
wipe the partition,
reinstall.